# PHP - clear the value on job title drop down list when reset button clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html

Department

```
dept_ID       dept_name
   1           Account
```

Job Title

```
job_title_ID       job_title_name      dept_ID
     1             Account Manager        1 
     2              Account Clerk         1
```

user.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-themes-1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.1/jquery-ui.js">   </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //---SELECT DEPARTMENT DROP DOWN LIST---
    $("#userdepartment").change(function(){
        var departmentID = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'change.php',
            data: {departmentID: departmentID},
            success: function(html)
            {
                 $("#userjobtitle").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="adduser" method="post" action="user.php">
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>Department:</td>
         <td>
             <select name="userdepartment" id="userdepartment">
             <?php
             //---Db connection---

             $query = "SELECT *
                       FROM department
                       ORDER BY dept_name ASC";
             $result = mysql_query($query);

             print("<option value=\"\">select one</option><br>");
             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
             {
                 print("<option value=\"" . $row['dept_ID'] . "\">" . $row['dept_name'] . "</option><br />");   
             }   
             ?>
             </select>
         </td> 
     </tr>

     <tr>
         <td>Job Title:</td>
         <td>
             <select name="userjobtitle" id="userjobtitle">
                  <option value="">select one</option>
             </select>
         </td>
     </tr>

    <tr>
         <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" /></td>
         <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

change.php

```
<?php
//---DB connection---

$departmentID = $_POST['departmentID'];

$q = "SELECT j.job_title_ID, j.job_title_name 
      FROM job_title j, department d
      WHERE j.job_title_dept = d.dept_ID && d.dept_ID = $departmentID";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

echo '<option value="">select one</option>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['job_title_ID'].'">'.$row['job_title_name'].'</option>';
} 
?>
```

From above code, when I select Account from department drop down list, job title drop down list will show Account Manager and Account Clerk. 
My question is when I click reset button, how should I clear the value in job title drop down list? This is because when I click reset button, the job title drop down list doesn't clear the value. Can somebody help me?

Comment: This is not a PHP job, unless you reload the whole page. You probably want to remove this in the user interface and that is done using JS. You could have done it in PHP, if your architecture would be different, like having a PHP service that returns the list and an AJAX request that queries for it

Answer (score 1):

Try emptying the select:

```
$('input[type="reset"]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
$('#userjobtitle').empty().append('<option value="">select one</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `Javascript` like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" onclick="reset();" />
```

Javascript:

```
function reset(){
  $('#userjobtitle').prop('selectedIndex',0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should clear it by jquery on onclick event, also any dropdown:

```
$('#userjobtitle').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use and onclick event

```
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"
       onclick="document.getElementById('userjobtitle').value='';" />
```